# sql: still create new row eventhough row exists

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, sql-update

i want to append new values to the existing event id and value. so i used `ON DUPLICATE KEY`. but why is sql writing new row eventhough the row has existed?
am i doing anything wrong? :'(

i'm using MySQL in phpmyadmin

my unique key: event_id

[image: my database]

```
INSERT INTO et_seats(event_id, reserved) VALUES ('$theatre->id', '$payment->seatnumber')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            reserved = reserved + '$comma' + '$payment->seatnumber'
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.